# Plotting spectrogram of signal (surface electromyography) using scipy and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, signals

I have a 60Hz frequency surface electromyography dataset stroed in torch tensor, which I would like to convert it to spectrogram to acquire image version. I tried to use scipy.signal.spectrogram and pcolormesh from matplotlib, but the result gives me a blank plot with only axis. The example of my data in one batch is as below:

```
tensor([1.4458e-02, 9.8201e-03, 8.8783e-03, 1.2674e-02, 8.1712e-03, 4.0293e-03,
        5.0523e-03, 3.7394e-03, 2.1965e-02, 2.4790e-02, 8.5859e-03, 1.3081e-02,
        6.4008e-03, 2.0409e-02, 3.0875e-02, 2.3617e-02, 3.3676e-02, 5.3449e-02,
        2.5645e-02, 1.3666e-02, 9.4334e-03, 2.2892e-02, 2.7402e-02, 2.2909e-02,
        4.3816e-02, 3.0607e-02, 7.8202e-04, 5.9660e-03, 1.3925e-02, 4.5966e-02,
        2.8455e-02, 1.4542e-03, 3.9536e-02, 1.4115e-02, 1.9775e-02, 2.2408e-02,
        5.0217e-03, 7.0494e-04, 3.1064e-03, 4.0066e-02, 9.3312e-03, 7.5034e-03,
        2.2241e-02, 2.9770e-02, 3.2652e-02, 1.1621e-02, 1.1621e-02, 2.0524e-02,
        1.5398e-02, 4.5158e-02, 3.9614e-02, 1.1103e-03, 1.3038e-03, 1.8396e-03,
        2.3575e-02, 5.2928e-02, 1.7184e-02, 1.4979e-02, 1.5802e-02, 1.3214e-02,
        1.5350e-02, 2.6884e-04, 1.9442e-02, 2.4871e-02, 2.6104e-02, 3.0045e-02,
        2.8420e-02, 4.0301e-03, 3.9526e-03, 1.5045e-02, 2.8030e-02, 2.5798e-02,
        2.5798e-02, 2.0892e-02, 2.9606e-02, 5.2186e-03, 1.7122e-03, 5.2519e-02,
        2.6752e-02, 1.3373e-02, 8.5243e-03, 3.6422e-03, 7.7749e-03, 1.1167e-02,
        1.4266e-02, 7.4657e-03, 7.8746e-03, 7.4677e-05, 1.1132e-03, 1.1489e-02,
        1.2060e-02, 1.0775e-02, 5.4699e-02, 3.5796e-02, 6.7368e-03, 1.9504e-02,
        2.6181e-02, 4.1793e-03, 3.9625e-03, 1.6326e-02, 2.2435e-02, 1.3888e-02,
        1.2613e-02, 2.4543e-02, 1.3389e-02, 4.0636e-03, 1.1115e-02, 4.2193e-02,
        1.4601e-02, 2.0686e-02, 4.4160e-03, 7.6157e-03, 1.5917e-02, 2.5257e-02,
        1.9146e-02, 1.1246e-02, 2.8330e-04, 8.7970e-03, 9.1066e-03, 1.5478e-02,
        1.1184e-02, 1.7199e-02, 3.2053e-02, 2.1027e-03, 2.8986e-03, 7.4544e-03,
        9.6567e-03, 4.6971e-03, 5.3027e-02, 6.2249e-02, 2.4887e-02, 1.2462e-02,
        1.9944e-02, 1.3925e-02, 1.0937e-02, 1.4913e-02, 1.0694e-02, 5.9187e-02,
        5.9187e-02, 5.9187e-02, 3.2870e-03, 1.1995e-02, 1.7444e-02, 4.0331e-03,
        1.6909e-02, 2.4710e-02, 1.1389e-02, 1.8584e-03, 1.6878e-02, 2.3752e-02,
        2.3752e-02, 1.9340e-02, 3.9648e-02, 1.7670e-02, 3.4614e-02, 6.7582e-03,
        1.1932e-02, 9.6085e-03, 4.9216e-03, 2.4596e-02, 4.6430e-03, 9.6705e-03,
        3.1486e-02, 9.9361e-03, 1.6469e-02, 6.0242e-03, 1.4003e-02, 3.5460e-02,
        1.1701e-02, 1.8429e-03, 1.0323e-02, 3.1715e-02, 3.6270e-02, 1.1964e-02,
        1.9469e-02, 1.6741e-02, 2.2261e-02, 4.1393e-02, 2.9687e-02, 1.4913e-02],
       dtype=torch.float64)
```

Can someone please give me an example how I can plot this into spectrogram?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
tenf = np.array([1.4458e-02, 9.8201e-03, 8.8783e-03, 1.2674e-02, 8.1712e-03, 4.0293e-03,
        5.0523e-03, 3.7394e-03, 2.1965e-02, 2.4790e-02, 8.5859e-03, 1.3081e-02,
        6.4008e-03, 2.0409e-02, 3.0875e-02, 2.3617e-02, 3.3676e-02, 5.3449e-02,
        2.5645e-02, 1.3666e-02, 9.4334e-03, 2.2892e-02, 2.7402e-02, 2.2909e-02,
        4.3816e-02, 3.0607e-02, 7.8202e-04, 5.9660e-03, 1.3925e-02, 4.5966e-02,
        2.8455e-02, 1.4542e-03, 3.9536e-02, 1.4115e-02, 1.9775e-02, 2.2408e-02,
        5.0217e-03, 7.0494e-04, 3.1064e-03, 4.0066e-02, 9.3312e-03, 7.5034e-03,
        2.2241e-02, 2.9770e-02, 3.2652e-02, 1.1621e-02, 1.1621e-02, 2.0524e-02,
        1.5398e-02, 4.5158e-02, 3.9614e-02, 1.1103e-03, 1.3038e-03, 1.8396e-03,
        2.3575e-02, 5.2928e-02, 1.7184e-02, 1.4979e-02, 1.5802e-02, 1.3214e-02,
        1.5350e-02, 2.6884e-04, 1.9442e-02, 2.4871e-02, 2.6104e-02, 3.0045e-02,
        2.8420e-02, 4.0301e-03, 3.9526e-03, 1.5045e-02, 2.8030e-02, 2.5798e-02,
        2.5798e-02, 2.0892e-02, 2.9606e-02, 5.2186e-03, 1.7122e-03, 5.2519e-02,
        2.6752e-02, 1.3373e-02, 8.5243e-03, 3.6422e-03, 7.7749e-03, 1.1167e-02,
        1.4266e-02, 7.4657e-03, 7.8746e-03, 7.4677e-05, 1.1132e-03, 1.1489e-02,
        1.2060e-02, 1.0775e-02, 5.4699e-02, 3.5796e-02, 6.7368e-03, 1.9504e-02,
        2.6181e-02, 4.1793e-03, 3.9625e-03, 1.6326e-02, 2.2435e-02, 1.3888e-02,
        1.2613e-02, 2.4543e-02, 1.3389e-02, 4.0636e-03, 1.1115e-02, 4.2193e-02,
        1.4601e-02, 2.0686e-02, 4.4160e-03, 7.6157e-03, 1.5917e-02, 2.5257e-02,
        1.9146e-02, 1.1246e-02, 2.8330e-04, 8.7970e-03, 9.1066e-03, 1.5478e-02,
        1.1184e-02, 1.7199e-02, 3.2053e-02, 2.1027e-03, 2.8986e-03, 7.4544e-03,
        9.6567e-03, 4.6971e-03, 5.3027e-02, 6.2249e-02, 2.4887e-02, 1.2462e-02,
        1.9944e-02, 1.3925e-02, 1.0937e-02, 1.4913e-02, 1.0694e-02, 5.9187e-02,
        5.9187e-02, 5.9187e-02, 3.2870e-03, 1.1995e-02, 1.7444e-02, 4.0331e-03,
        1.6909e-02, 2.4710e-02, 1.1389e-02, 1.8584e-03, 1.6878e-02, 2.3752e-02,
        2.3752e-02, 1.9340e-02, 3.9648e-02, 1.7670e-02, 3.4614e-02, 6.7582e-03,
        1.1932e-02, 9.6085e-03, 4.9216e-03, 2.4596e-02, 4.6430e-03, 9.6705e-03,
        3.1486e-02, 9.9361e-03, 1.6469e-02, 6.0242e-03, 1.4003e-02, 3.5460e-02,
        1.1701e-02, 1.8429e-03, 1.0323e-02, 3.1715e-02, 3.6270e-02, 1.1964e-02,
        1.9469e-02, 1.6741e-02, 2.2261e-02, 4.1393e-02, 2.9687e-02, 1.4913e-02],
       dtype=float)
stft1, stft2, stft3 = signal.stft(tenf)
plt.pcolormesh(stft2, stft1, abs(stft3), shading='auto')
plt.show()
```

[image]